# Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ be an uncountable set. Prove that $A\cap A'\neq\emptyset$.

Tags: analysis

$A'$ is the set of accumulation points of $A$.

I first proved that $A'\neq\emptyset$, after I tried construct a Cauchy's sequence to show anything, but it's not so useful...

Comment: What is $A'$ supposed to represent?

Comment: acumulation points of $A$

Comment: Use the fact that isolated points of $A$ form an at most countable set.

Comment: Indeed! How $\mathbb{R}$ is separable then subset so is, I forget. Thanks.

Comment: @Kempa A little warning: in general, a subspace of a separable space need not be separable. However, $A$ must indeed be separable: $\mathbb{R}$ is second-countable, a subspace of a second-countable space is itself second-countable, and every second-countable space is separable.

Comment: Where I can read more about this? @SamuelM.A.Luque

Comment: @Kempa Any basic general topology text would work: the famous Topology by Munkres, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \in A\setminus A'$, then there must be some $\epsilon=\epsilon(x)>0$ such that $(x,x+\epsilon) \cap A  =\emptyset$. We can select some rational number $q(x) \in \mathbb Q \cap (x,x+\epsilon)$.
The mapping $x \mapsto q(x)$ is injective, so $A\setminus A'$ is countable.